# table types in Mysql?

Tags: mysql

what exactly are the transactional storage engines in MySQL ?? also please get me something in detail about the various table types for MySQL.....

Comment: You can find lot of information on MySQL site and http://dev.mysql.com/

Comment: i should have asked a more basic question.. what exactly is a storage engine in mysql??? its use and where is lies???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/storage-engines.html

Here you go, a full list of storage engines which MySQL supports (transactional and nontransactional). *Some probably aren't enabled by default.*